# rbenv is not initialized properly from automatic deployment

Tags: ruby, bash, rbenv

I am writing app for deployment. I have working rbenv environment on Debian 10. For all users, rbenv is initalized properly, so in project directories proper ruby version is used.

But when I try to run from web app using `Kernel.system` or just ``` `` ```, it fails, it is used Ruby version of my web-app. I am trying to initalize it but in `$PATH` is still bad version.

If I use `/var/www/.rbenv/bin/rbenv local` then `ruby -v` prints proper version, but mina deployment fails trying to load gems from local vendor directory of web app project.

When I do this from padrino console usning system():

`/var/www/.rbenv/bin/rbenv local && ruby -v`

It returns

`"2.6.5\nruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]\n"`

So rbenv local works fine but another command uses bad ruby version.

Please is there any way to initialize proper version?

EDIT: Answers to questions.

It is web app for deploying on local server of another ruby apps, we have a lots of versions. Web app is running (just this app) on Ruby 3.0.0. I am executing command inside directory of app which I want to deploy (Ruby 2.6.5) using mina, but it failed.

`which ruby` from padrino console

`/var/www/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/ruby\n`

And PATH

`=> "/var/www/production/deploy/releases/77/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin:/var/www/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin:/var/www/.rbenv/libexec:/var/www/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/var/www/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-vars/bin:/var/www/.rbenv/shims:/var/www/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\n"`

As you can see, it is 3.0.0.

When I try to run command in kernel system this

`cd /var/www/deploy/build/project_to_be_deployed && mina deploy` it fails because it tries to use ruby 3 instead of 2.6.5, if I try to switch using rbenv using rbenv local or changing value of RBENV_VERSION it shows me proper 2.6.5 but everyr command is executed under 3.0.0

Maybe I am explaining poorly. Every command is runned from ruby code, using system() call. On bash everything works fine! The problem is I think in the forking of bash or loading the environment during execution of command from ruby

Comment: What is the output of `which ruby`? What is the value of `$PATH`? Without knowing what you've currently done, there's little advice we can give other than point you towards to official `rbenv` documentation - which is also easy to find on google.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your web server ? It looks like what you want is rbenv to inject shims at the beginning of the PATH of the user running your webserver

Comment: Thanks both, I added info into question

Comment: So you see the problem in your `$PATH`, right? Systems read the `$PATH` from left-to-right. So somehow, for whatever reason, you've got `...../ruby/3.0.0/bin` as the leftmost thing in your `$PATH`, and therefore it's always going to pick up (the SYSTEM) ruby `3.0.0` instead of the `rbenv` ruby version.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're even installing system-ruby on the production machine, if you also plan to install it through rbenv... And I'm also not sure why you've ended up with `..../.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin` in the `$PATH`. But clearly something dodgy is setup in the deployment script and/or production machine setup.

Comment: It is not system-ruby it was experiment with another user, all production rubies are managed with rbenv. I need to deploy app through the tool for deployment (tool is ruby 3 but app is 2.6.5), if I run system(command) trying to run mina deploy in the folder of the app to be deployed, ruby version of deploy app is used instead of the version of the project to be deployed. Deploy app is new project under development. If I run in the app folder mina manually it works fine (of course).

Comment: So I think that the problem is that in the moment of execution of mina it is not loaded proper ruby version from folder settings, my variables are in the question, but I don't know how to perform system(command) to use ruby version from the folder where it is executed. I added explanation into question. I am stuck for a day on this :(